# 814: unexpected token at 'FORBIDDEN'

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following controller - recipes_controller.rb:

```
class RecipesController < ApplicationController
  def list
    @search_term = params[:looking_for] || 'chicken'
    @courses = Recipe.for(@search_term)
  end
end
```

The following model: recipes.rb:

```
require 'httparty'

class Recipe
    include HTTParty

    default_options.update(verify: false)

    base_uri 'http://food2fork.com/api/search'
    default_params key: ENV['FOOD2FORK_KEY']
    format :json

    def self.for term
        get("", query: { q: term})["recipes"]
    end
end
```

& the following view- list.html.erb:

```
<h1>Searching for - <%= @search_term %></h1>

<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>Image</th>
        <th>Publisher</th>
        <th>Title</th>
    </tr>
    <% @courses.each do |course| %>
    <tr class=<%= cycle('even', 'odd') %>>
        <td><%= image_tag(course["image_url"])%></td>
        <td><%= course["publisher"] %></td>
        <td><%= course["title"] %></td>
    </tr>
    <% end %>
</table>
```

When I do http://localhost:3000/recipes/list, it gives me the following error:

814: unexpected token at 'FORBIDDEN'

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/models/recipe.rb:13:in `for'
app/controllers/recipes_controller.rb:4:in`list'

the json is of the following format:

```
{"count": 1, "recipes": [{"publisher": "Tasty Kitchen", "f2f_url": "http://food2fork.com/view/459b3d", "title": "End the Search Chocolate Chip Cookies", "source_url": "http://tastykitchen.com/recipes/desserts/end-the-search-chocolate-chip-cookiese280a6/", "recipe_id": "459b3d", "image_url": "http://static.food2fork.com/cookie2410x307a33e.jpg", "social_rank": 34.80777735743579, "publisher_url": "http://tastykitchen.com"}]}
```

Please let me know what to do.

Comment: Have you retried constructing the url that the get request is for manually? Looks to me like you're most likely getting a 403 from the API you're issuing requests against.

Comment: @photoionized : http://food2fork.com/api/search?key=a11111111111111&q=search This is the url that gives the above json. But when I do http://food2fork.com/api/search, I get 403 forbidden. What should the base uri be in this case?

Comment: I have no idea, never used that API before, but to me it doesn't look like it's an API base url thing, but more likely an invalid authentication key.

Comment: @photoionized So, instead of putting FOOD2FORK_KEY in my key, I put the actual key in my code, and now the error goes, but it doesn't show any data pulled from the json. It just shows the table heads.

Comment: Can you throw something like a pry statement into the `Recipe.for` method and see what the return value of `get("", query: { query: term})["recipes"]` is?

Comment: @photoionized: Could you tell me how do I create a search field where I can enter a word, and then it sets it as the keyword in the url returning its list of recipes. I've updated my question with the working code, where keyword to search is typed in the url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I just went and signed up for a food2fork.com api key and read their documentation, there are a couple of issues with your code.

1. If you take a look under the search api documentation, you'll see the explanation of the query parameters:

   ```
   q: (optional) Search Query (Ingredients should be separated by commas). If this is omitted top rated recipes will be returned.
   ```

   What that means is that you're sending a request for a recipe with ingredients of "keyword" with every request you're making. Obviously there are no recipes with an ingredient named keyword.
2. If you look in the same section, there seems to be no query parameters for "fields," so you shouldn't be adding them. It doesn't hurt, but why have code that does nothing in your class?
3. You're likely wanting to get your key from the environment rather than hardcoding it into your app.

All that being said, I think you want something like this as your Recipe class:

```
require 'httparty'

class Recipe
    include HTTParty

    default_options.update(verify: false)

    base_uri 'http://food2fork.com/api/search'
    default_params key: ENV['FOOD2FORK_KEY']
    format :json

    def self.for term        
        get("", query: { q: term })["recipes"]
    end
end
```

Comment: Yes, I get it, but you aren't passing any keyword now right? What if I want to search something like 'chocolate'? The results displayed remain the same in your case even if I do something like:http://localhost:3000/recipes/list?looking_for=chocolate. So how do I pass this "keyword"?

Comment: @user3591433 great, if this answer helped you, please consider accepting it.